# Social Stream Rapidweaver stack using to keep track of facebook page's feed

Tags: facebook

So I just bought the Social Stream stack plugin for Rapidweaver and am having trouble integrating my facebook page into it. I know I need an Access Token and a "User or Tag". How do I find the User or Tag for my page? Once I have that it's just a simple matter of using facebook's Graph API tool to find the access token correct? Can't find hardly any documentation on the social stream plugin and this is a last resort. My page is a local business if that helps narrow anything down.

Comment: See if that helps: http://www.rapid-ideas.com/neu/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/SocialStreamStack.pdf

Comment: Alas, I've already been through there. I've got the user in. tried using the numeric id instead of username, and nothing I've tried works. doesn't even show up on the page at all when I push it to my development website. >:( So very frustrating.

Comment: Querying user information via username is not possible any more since Facebook introduced API v2.0. But since you bought a commercial product here, I think the service provider should be happy enough helping you out with the problems you are having with it – so try and contact them for help.